# OpenRDF Sesame - 404 error

Tags: tomcat, rdf, sesame

I have OpenRDF Sesame in my webapps folder under my Apache Tomcat installation.  I can access the /openrdf-workbench webapp, but /openrdf-sesame gives me a 404 error.

Literally all it says is:

```
HTTP Status 404 -

type Status report

message

description The requested resource () is not available.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.26
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a [known issue (SES-845)](https://openrdf.atlassian.net/browse/SES-845) in OpenRDF Sesame in combination with Tomcat 7. The Sesame server runs normally, but there is a problem with the redirect handler in the servlet that handles rendering the HTML interface. As a workaround you can directly access the address `openrdf-sesame/home/overview.view` from your browser.

Comment: This solution solve web-browser acces to the sesame server, but don't resolve access to server from Eclipse. for example 'Repository myRepository = new HTTPRepository("http://localhost:8080/openrdf-sesame", "soctrace1");' still not work. Any idea of how to mahage this?

Comment: That would be a completely unrelated issue - the above answer is strictly about redirects in the browser and has nothing to do with API access to Sesame. If you've encountered difficulties accessing a Sesame server from Java I suggest you open a new question, with details about your setup and what is going wrong (any errors, log messages, etc).

Comment: Thank for your advice, Here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19627225/how-to-access-sesame-server-from-eclipse