# sesame 2.6.9 with tomcat 7 set up won't work

Tags: tomcat7, sesame

I was trying to install sesame. 
I first followed these instructions: http://www.openrdf.org/doc/sesame2/users/ch06.html

To install tomcat as a prerequesite I used this tutorial: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/installing-tomcat-6-on-ubuntu/ (I stopped before the automatic starting part)

The set up tutorial says "The deployment process is container-specific, please consult the documentation for your container on how to deploy a web application."
according to this tutorial: http://www.snee.com/bobdc.blog/2009/02/getting-started-with-sesame.htmlmit says

"To install a Sesame server on top of Tomcat, I copied the two war files from openrdf-sesame-2.2.4\war to apache-tomcat-6.0.18\webapps. After I shut down and restarted Tomcat, sending my browser to ttp://localhost:8080/openrdf-workbench and ttp://localhost:8080/openrdf-sesame showed welcome screens about how these apps were running with no problem."

Which I did. ttp://localhost:8080 shows a tomcat welcome page, ttp://localhost:8080/openrdf-workbench shows a site, but ttp://localhost:8080/openrdf-sesame gives only a 404 error. I also can't do anything on the workbench site, as it forces one to stay on the "Change Server" input field. Trying to just type in the path as proposed by "i.e. ttp://localhost:8080/openrdf-sesame" below the input fiels only says "Invalid Server URL"
On top of the page it also says

```
Current Selections
Sesame server   none    change
Repository  none    change
```

which just looks totally diffrent than how it should be, as like here: http://www.jenitennison.com/blog/node/153

I digged a bit more around and found this: http://www.openrdf.org/doc/sesame/users/ch02.html
But it seems outdated, as there is simply no [SESAME_DIR]/WEB-INF/system.conf.example in there. 
I also found this: http://www.openrdf.org/forum/mvnforum/viewthread?thread=658 But there is also no "example-file" to be renamed.

Also I have shutdown tomcat with the shutdown.sh script in the tomcat bin folder and restarted it with the startup.sh script several times, but that doesn't seem to help any bit either.

Am I missing something? As the "Getting started with Sesame" Blogpost indicated copying them to the webapps folder should have been enough, but it is not working right...

Thanks for any help!

---

EDIT 1:
The workaround with the direct access to localhost:8080/openrdf-sesame/home/overview.view does unfortunately not work either. What I also don't understand, if the Sesame Server were running properly and the trouble were only with the redirect, the workbench should find the server, which is just not the case.

---

EDIT 2:
the catalina.2012-11-01.log contains the following:

```
Nov 01, 2012 11:49:28 AM org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.WorkbenchGateway canConnect
WARNING: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:8080/openrdf-sesame/protocol
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:8080/openrdf-sesame/protocol
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1613)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1037)
    at org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.WorkbenchGateway.canConnect(WorkbenchGateway.java:130)
    at org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.WorkbenchGateway.isValidServer(WorkbenchGateway.java:303)
    at org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.WorkbenchGateway.findWorkbenchServlet(WorkbenchGateway.java:209)
    at org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.WorkbenchGateway.service(WorkbenchGateway.java:100)
    at org.openrdf.workbench.base.BaseServlet.service(BaseServlet.java:40)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.CookieCacheControlFilter.doFilter(CookieCacheControlFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

It seems looking for some protocol file, but that file doesn't even exist in the war package, so I am kind of clueless what it wants...

---

EDIT 3:
So while trying to figure out what the heck was wrong I tired looking it up according to below answer to look it up with the Tomcat's web application manager. While I still don't get that one to work (keeping to get "403 Access Denied" errors depite editing the tomcat-users.xml), something along the way must have been accidentially done the magic. My only guess is that shutting it down and restarting it at least a dozen times may have helped, as I really didn't do anything else than editing the tomcat-users.xml file and restarting it each time tryingto get the manager working. I have no clue, why that wouldn't have helped before, through, I did restart tomcat at least four times before.

Comment: There is a redirect issue with Tomcat 7 and Sesame. See this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501765/openrdf-sesame-404-error for solution

Comment: The documentation link mentioning system.conf.example is out of date, that's for Sesame 1, which is no longer supported.

Comment: Regarding the problem with the workbench not connecting: that seems like your Sesame server is not properly booting up. Can you check your Tomcat logs for any clues as to what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice but slightly out of date walk-through [here](http://gasw.blogspot.co.uk/2010/09/deploying-sesamewar-into-tomcat.html), which gave me the key tip I needed when I ran into the same trouble you mentioned above.

This strategy has one key difference: it deploys the WAR file (for me: `/home/joe/sesame/core/http/server/target/openrdf-sesame.war`) *from within the Tomcat Manager* (`http://localhost:8080`), rather than via the `jar -xf [PATH/TO/]sesame.war` command-line invocation from [the docs](http://www.openrdf.org/doc/sesame/users/ch02.html#d0e233).  Perhaps the key feature is just that it deploys to `openrdf-sesame` rather than `sesame`...

In any case, now when I visit `http://localhost:8080/openrdf-sesame/home/overview.view` I get a complaint that I'm not using the OpenRDF Workbench... but otherwise all is well.

Answer (score 0):

The FileNotFoundException indicates that the Sesame server is not running. However, it does not tell us *why* it is not running. Can you doublecheck that you've deployed the `openrdf-sesame.war` file correctly? Is the OpenRDF Sesame webapp listed (and started) if you enter Tomcat's web application manager? Are there any other errors or warnings in the tomcat logs that indicate problems?

If it is deployed correctly, another possible cause is that the Sesame server has insufficient permissions to write to disk. Sesame creates an application data dir for configuration files and for persisting data, by default (on Linux) in `$HOME/.aduna` (where $HOME is the homedir of the user under which Tomcat runs). Can you verify that it has sufficient permissions to write there? I vaguely remember this being a problem with the default Tomcat setup that comes with the Ubuntu Linux distribution.

If you can't change the permissions, you can also configure a different location for Sesame to use as datadir. See the [Sesame docs, chapter 5](http://www.openrdf.org/doc/sesame2/users/ch05.html), for details.

Comment: I have copied the war file to /usr/local/tomcat/webapps, the contents of the var file are now in the /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/openrdf-sesame folder, it seems complete, and according to that tutorial no more is nescessary.
The logs contain no other error. Unfortunately I can't get the web application manager to run, it keeps giving me "403 Access Denied" erros, despite configuring the tomcat-users.xml file and restarting tomcat several times. No idea, what went wrong there, either in the moment...
The server should have permissions, but I will double check on that again.

Comment: drwxr-xr-x 3 hduser hadoop 4096 Okt 31 16:47 ./

drwxr-xr-x 7 hduser hadoop 4096 Okt 31 16:47 ../

drwxr-xr-x 5 hduser hadoop 4096 Okt 31 16:47 openrdf-sesame/

in the .arduna folder, so yes, there should be writing rights

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this answer is not going to be of much help to you after all this time, but I had the EXACT same problem as you and I found a solution that worked for me.
In my case it was simply a problem of permissions: once I run

```
chmod -R 777 /location/of/my/webapps
```

everything started working smoothly. I hope that this can help anybody who stumbles on this problem.

ps: please note that setting 777 permissions on any folder is often considered unwise, so try to consult the man page for chmod and try some combinations to see which one suits you best.