# Sesame 2.7.11 Change Server message

Tags: java, tomcat, ubuntu, sesame

After I added more RAM to my machine, I restarted it. I discovered that Sesame is not working anymore and I keep getting the Change Server message.

I use Sesame 2.7.11, with Apache Tomcat 7-0.53 and Java 1.7.0_51_b13 on Ubuntu 13.10.

Here is the Tomcat error log:

```
May 20, 2014 6:29:55 PM org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.ServerValidator checkServerPrefixes
WARNING: server URL null does not have a prefix file: http: https:
May 20, 2014 6:29:55 PM org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.ServerValidator canConnect
WARNING: java.net.UnknownHostException: localhost
java.net.UnknownHostException: localhost
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
    ...
    at org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.ServerValidator.canConnect(ServerValidator.java:121)
    at org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.ServerValidator.isValidServer(ServerValidator.java:76)
    at org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.WorkbenchGateway.findWorkbenchServlet(WorkbenchGateway.java:251)
    at org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.WorkbenchGateway.service(WorkbenchGateway.java:121)
    at org.openrdf.workbench.base.BaseServlet.service(BaseServlet.java:136)
    ...
```

I am aware that there is a similar question ([sesame 2.6.9 with tomcat 7 set up won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13163410/sesame-2-6-9-with-tomcat-7-set-up-wont-work)), but the Tomcat error in my case seems to be different. Instead of localhost in my actual log you can find the address of my web server (so let's say data.something.com).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What causes the error - java.net.UnknownHostException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484275/what-causes-the-error-java-net-unknownhostexception)

Comment: Hi @JeenBroekstra the error might be that one, but the fix I typically used (delete the settings from the .aduna folder and restart Tomcat) does not really work. The problem is I do not have any .aduna folder on my server. Do I need to reinstall Sesame and create that .aduna folder as explained here: http://agacho.blogspot.co.at/2012/08/installing-sesame-server-on-ubuntu-1204.html

Comment: @JeenBroekstra I found in the end the .aduna folder. I removed the locks. Still not working. Same Change Server error. Is there any reference in the Sesame documentation to what exactly do I need to change in this situation?

Comment: The "Change Server" error? What's that, exactly? You're only showing a stacktrace here for a UnknownHostException. And why would you be removing the locks in Sesame's datadir? As far as I can tell this problem is not related to the other post you found at all - it's a completely different error.

Comment: I just had to add the address of the server in the Change Server page, but that was hard to understand from the documentation (there is only a short mention of it here: http://openrdf.callimachus.net/sesame/2.7/docs/users.docbook?view#Setting_the_Server__Repository_and_User_Credentials). You were right that it was a different error. Thanks for help! @JeenBroekstra

Answer (score 1):

The answer can be found here: http://openrdf.callimachus.net/sesame/2.7/docs/users.docbook?view#Setting_the_Server__Repository_and_User_Credentials

Essentially if the workbench can't find the server and keeps loading the Change Server page, it's ok to add the IP in the Change Server page, and it should work.