# Creating a sesame repository from eclipse connecting to the http server

Tags: java, eclipse, repository, rdf, sesame

I can connect to `localhost:8080/openrdf-sesame/` and create a new repository from **Sesame console**. I am using Tomcat server everything is fine about that. I can also connect to `localhost:8080/openrdf-workbench/` and display/delete repositories

But when I type `localhost:8080/openrdf-sesame/` to my browser, I am getting error. Why? So I can't access an existing repository from Eclipse simply giving `localhost:8080/openrdf-sesame/` to `HTTPRepository`. I import rdf jar's to the project so no problem about that

My java code:

```
String sesameServer = "http://localhost:8080/openrdf-sesame";
String repositoryID = "1001";

Repository repo = new HTTPRepository(sesameServer, repositoryID);
repo.initialize();
```

The repository id '1001' is really existing in the repository. I can see it from workbench.

The eclipse says millions(!) of lines that error type:

```
...
15:18:51.843 [main] DEBUG o.a.commons.httpclient.HttpClient - Operating system version: 3.5.0-23-generic
...
```

Comment: It would help if you showed the actual error message you get (a complete error message not a trivial fragment).  You may also want to see your log level to INFO or higher to avoid getting full HTTP debug info from Apache HTTP Client.  Also have you tried just adding the trailing slash to the end of the `sesameServer` value?

Comment: There is something missing I realize now: 2 war files from sesame directory should be deployed to the eclipse. So I downloaded the J2EE version of eclipse, but when I import one war file it is creating a new project. I think it shouldnt create a new project. What should I do for these 2 war files to eclipse? I tried slash at the end but it didnt work by the way, thanks for it. I cant write all lines of code here but the writable ones I am posting:

Comment: letter capacity for message contains just those,sorry17:13:33.317 [main] DEBUG o.o.rio.DatatypeHandlerRegistry - Registered service class org.openrdf.rio.datatypes.XMLSchemaDatatypeHandler
17:13:33.320 [main] DEBUG o.o.rio.DatatypeHandlerRegistry - Registered service class org.openrdf.rio.datatypes.RDFDatatypeHandler
17:13:33.320 [main] DEBUG o.o.rio.DatatypeHandlerRegistry - Registered service class org.openrdf.rio.datatypes.DBPediaDatatypeHandler
17:13:33.321 [main] DEBUG o.o.rio.DatatypeHandlerRegistry - Registered service class org.openrdf.rio.datatypes.VirtuosoGeometryDatatypeHandler

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501765/openrdf-sesame-404-error

Comment: I don't think you actually have an error (apart from the problem in the browser, which is a known issue, see the above link to a near-duplicate question). The log entries you show are just debug output, they're not errors. Have you actually tried to use the HTTPRepository object from Eclipse (e.g. open a connection, do a query, process the result)?